# Entity Framework Model Builder Configuration using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-6

I want to call the below code using reflection:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CardPayment>().Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
                m.ToTable("CardPayments");
            });
```

I am trying the following:

```
var entityMethod = typeof(DbModelBuilder).GetMethod("Entity");
entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type)
          .Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { });
```

How do I call the "**Map**" method with the parameters supplying the "Map" method.
How can I invoke the "**MapInheritedProperties**" and "**ToTable**" methods within the "Map" method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the return object from `entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { });`, then you can dynamically invoke `Map`:

```
var mapLambda = 
      /* you'll need to fix the typing here */(m) => 
      { 
           m.MapInheritedProperties();
           m.ToTable("CardPayments");
      };

var entityMethod = typeof(DbModelBuilder).GetMethod("Entity");
var entityResult = 
     entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type)
          .Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { });

//invoke Map
entityResult.GetType().GetMethod("Map").Invoke(entityResult, new object[]{ mapLambda });
```